# How do I fix these dependency issues from default "rails new app" and "npx create-react-app"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, node-modules, create-react-app, webpacker

I'm trying to create a new rails app using default settings along with a folder inside for the client using npx create-react-app. For some reason everything installs fine but I can't figure out why the webpack version numbers aren't matching my default. I keep getting this error everytime I cd inside of the client folder and try to yarn start..

Just for clarification my npx create-react-app client was run inside of myapp folder...so react currently lives in.../Users/JohnnyBrown/Desktop/myapp/client

I dont understand how I'm having webpack version issues off default commands...

When using -v in terminal heres my version number for everything:

rails version 6.0, 
yarn v - 1.17.0, 
npm -v 6.9.0, 
node -v 10.13.0 
webpack -v 4.34.0

I've already tried the options it offers which is deleting things up the tree but this hasn't worked.. at the very least I can't even get the .env file to work maybe I'm not putting it in the right place? Any insight would be much appreciated..

````
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.41.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/JohnnyBrown/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.41.2) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /Users/JohnnyBrown/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.```
````

Answer (score 0):

check if you dont have node_modules outside your project folder.. you have to delete it and run "npm start" again